# Sound coming from an uninstalled chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a reoccurring sound coming from an uninstalled Chrome extension. There was a chrome extension called 20/20/20 which would play a sound every 20 minutes. The extension was later removed from the Chrome store. I manually removed the extension shortly after. The sound from the extension is still appearing, but it is now playing at random intervals (40 min, 60 min, 100 min, etc.).

I have uninstalled Chrome, cleared all browsing data, and ensured the files from 'Appdata' and 'Program Files' were also removed. When I reinstall Chrome, the sound comes back. Are there any suggestions for how I can handle this bug?

Comment: It must be coming from another extension.